# Rename folders from file name [script]

Tags: scripts, rename

I want rename every folder with the name of the single file inside.
Example:

```
Folder1/AAA.jpg
Folder2/BBB.jpg
FOlder3/CCC.jpg
Folder4/05.02.2019.jpg

to

AAA/AAA.jpg
BBB/BBB.jpg
CCC/CCC.jpg
05.02.2019/05.02.2019.jpg
```

In windows I can do it with this script in a simple file batch:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  for %%b in ("%%a\*.jpg","%%a\*.png") do (
     ren "%%a" "%%~nb"
  )
)
```

In Ubuntu I have tried but maybe I'm writing wrong syntax. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you show us the syntax you used in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is almost analogical bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in Folder*/*
do
    FILE="$(basename "$i")"
    mv "$(dirname "$i")" "${FILE%.*}"
done
```

Example of usage:

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── Folder1
│   └── some name.png
└── Folder2
    └── 03.02.2019.jpg

2 directories, 2 files

$ for i in Folder*/*; do FILE="$(basename "$i")"; mv "$(dirname "$i")" "${FILE%.*}"; done

$ tree
.
├── 03.02.2019
│   └── 03.02.2019.jpg
└── some name
    └── some name.png

2 directories, 2 files
```

If you need to check whether the *extension* is *jpg* or *png*:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in Folder*/*
do
    if [[ $i =~ (jpg|png)$ ]]
    then
        FILE="$(basename "$i")"
        mv "$(dirname "$i")" "${FILE%.*}"
    fi
done
```

You can remove the limitation of the directory name by using `*/*` instead of `Folder*/*`. Also you can modify the relevant line to `echo mv "$(dirname "$i")" "${FILE%.*}"` for dry run test.

Further reading:

- [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)
- [Bash Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)
- [Bash Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- [Bash Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)
- [Bash The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)
- [Bash Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: Thank you pa4080. It works perfect

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they are all in the same parent directory:

```
for f in */*.jpg ; do mv "$(dirname "$f")" "$(basename "$f" .jpg)" ; done
```

In slow-mo:

- `*/*.jpg` will list `Folder1/AAA.jpg`,`Folder2/BBB.jpg`,`FOlder3/CCC.jpg`
- `$(dirname "$f")` extracts `Folder1`,`Folder2`,`FOlder3`
- `"$(basename "$f" .jpg)"` extracts the file name and drops the extension: `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`...
- So you end up with `mv Folder1 AAA`, `mv Folder2 BBB`...

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to handle both .jpg and .png suffixes - that's tricky to do with `basename` but could be done with shell parameter expansion e.g. `for p in */*.*; do f="${p##*/}"; echo mv -- "${p%%/*}" "${f%.*}"; done`

Answer (score 0):

This bash script changes folder names.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter old foldername
read oldfoldername
echo Enter new foldername
read newfoldername
mv $oldfoldername $newfoldername
```

```
Usage: bash {filename you copied script into}.sh
```